# Keras model.get_config() raises error in deepcopy (MaskRCNN)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am working with the MaskRCNN repo 
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py

Here in line 2064 in model.py before returning the built model back I want to extract the config using `model.get_config()`

I get the following error. Since the entire network is built before

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./samples/coco/coco.py", line 460, in <module>
    model_dir=args.logs)
  File "/mask_rcnn_root/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py", line 2063, in build
    print(self.keras_model.get_config())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 926, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 223, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 166, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
```